# How to convert ndarray to series in python

Tags: python, pandas, multidimensional-array

I have a `ndarray` like this one:

```
In [75]:
z_r
Out[75]:
array([[ 0.00909254],
       [ 0.02390291],
       [ 0.02998752]])
```

In here, I want to ask how to convert those things to `series`, the desired output is like this:

```
0   0.00909254
1   0.02390291
2   0.02998752
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use this one:

```
my_list = map(lambda x: x[0], z_r)
ser = pd.Series(my_list)
In [86]:
ser
Out[86]:
0      0.009093
1      0.023903
2      0.029988
```

Actually, your question is how to convert to series ^^

Comment: @ markov zain:  I'd rename this to 'Ndarray of Ndarrays to Series' because it describes your data more accurately. If it is just an ndarray of values, it does not work. Ex: array([ 0.00909254, 0.02390291, 0.02998752]), does not work with this code.

Answer (score 10):

`pd.Series(my_ndarray)`

no need to convert it first to a list then to series.

Comment: that doesnt work as that data isn't 1-dimensional

Answer (score 5):

```
z_r.tolist()
```

Comment: just a quick note: this doesn't create a pandas series it converts the ndarray to a list: [[0.00909254], [0.02390291], [0.02998752]].

Comment: Just wrap it with `pd.Series()`

Comment: I found your method better and more readable. Is the accepted answer converting the array to 1d array and then convert it to series? Is `map(lambda x: x[0], z_r)` doing the same thing as `tolist()`? Thanks

Comment: @BowenLiu Try it.